# Is there any way to get back the cancelled order?

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise

I have cancelled an order in magento, I need to get back the order with status pending and wanted to process the same order again. Is there any possibility of doing it.

Comment: If you're using a payment gateway, it might not be possible because that transaction is voided. You would have to hit "Re-Order" and re-create the order.

Comment: i tried the mamoc extension and it´s true that a uncancel button appears but it seems to do nothing. It sends me to the backend homepage. The order still canceled. Someone have used it with success???

Comment: @Nived: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 13):

**Massive props to Marius** for reminding me that there are columns that are updated with canceled data.

```
$incrementId = '1000001'; //replace this with the increment id of your actual order
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->setStatus('pending');

$order->setBaseDiscountCanceled(0);
$order->setBaseShippingCanceled(0);
$order->setBaseSubtotalCanceled(0);
$order->setBaseTaxCanceled(0);
$order->setBaseTotalCanceled(0);
$order->setDiscountCanceled(0);
$order->setShippingCanceled(0);
$order->setSubtotalCanceled(0);
$order->setTaxCanceled(0);
$order->setTotalCanceled(0);

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
    $item->setQtyCanceled(0);
    $item->setTaxCanceled(0);
    $item->setHiddenTaxCanceled(0);
    $item->save();
}

$order->save();
```

Voila!

Comment: You are on the right track, but there is more than that. You also need to change some other fields like `total_qty_canceled` (or something like that), you also need to change the state of the ordered items. It may be more but  this popped into my mind now.

Comment: X-O gosh you're totally right lol

Comment: That's more like it. I knew you can do it :)

Comment: See this script here, just used it and it is based on this answer: https://gist.github.com/derak-kilgo/3b778f49c2ba6b680bab6d1a1fa76daf

Comment: Wouldn't we need to also touch the product model to take the product back out of stock? Or is there an observer on Mage_Sale_Model_Order_Item?

Answer (score 7):

All other answers are not considering the product stock... (and neither do the extensions mentioned... I've checked the code).

There is an observer defined in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml`

```
            <sales_order_item_cancel>
            <observers>
                <inventory>
                    <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                    <method>cancelOrderItem</method>
                </inventory>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_item_cancel>
```

And that observer increases the stock when an order is cancelled...

```
    /**
 * Cancel order item
 *
 * @param   Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return  Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer
 */
public function cancelOrderItem($observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

    $children = $item->getChildrenItems();
    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered() - max($item->getQtyShipped(), $item->getQtyInvoiced()) - $item->getQtyCanceled();

    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    if ($item->getId() && $productId && empty($children) && $qty) {
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->backItemQty($productId, $qty);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

To fully uncancel an order, not only do we need to deal with the order as demonstrated by @philwinkle:

We also need to decrement the product quantity, and for this I believe that we need to reproduce the code from another observer registered in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml` and fires when an order is placed.

```
<sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
    <observers>
        <inventory>
            <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
            <method>subtractQuoteInventory</method>
        </inventory>
    </observers>
</sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
```

The observer function registers a products sale, but also sets a reindex flag...

```
/**
 * Subtract quote items qtys from stock items related with quote items products.
 *
 * Used before order placing to make order save/place transaction smaller
 * Also called after every successful order placement to ensure subtraction of inventory
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function subtractQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    // Maybe we've already processed this quote in some event during order placement
    // e.g. call in event 'sales_model_service_quote_submit_before' and later in 'checkout_submit_all_after'
    if ($quote->getInventoryProcessed()) {
        return;
    }
    $items = $this->_getProductsQty($quote->getAllItems());

    /**
     * Remember items
     */
    $this->_itemsForReindex = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->registerProductsSale($items);

    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true);
    return $this;
}
```

`registerProductsSale()` is expecting an array, but an array containing what values? The function's docbloc doesn't give us much of a hint...

```
/**
 * Subtract product qtys from stock.
 * Return array of items that require full save
 *
 * @param array $items
 * @return array
 */
```

whoopie its an array - as I said not very helpful... however, if we step into it, we see that the first line calls `$qtys = $this->_prepareProductQtys($items)`:

and the docbloc for this function is a lot more helpful...

```
/**
 * Prepare array($productId=>$qty) based on array($productId => array('qty'=>$qty, 'item'=>$stockItem))
 *
 * @param array $items
 */
```

ahh... `Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->registerProductsSale($items)` is expecting `array($productId => array('qty'=>$qty, 'item'=>$stockItem))`

and the code itself:

```
if (empty($item['item'])) {
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
}
```

shows that if $stockItem is empty it will helpfully instantiate it from the productId, meaning that we only really need to pass `array($productId => array('qty'=>$qty)`

At this point we might think we are finished... but hold your horses... 
According to [this Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107897/magento-1-relationship-between-qty-in-stock-item-and-stock-status-tables) we're not done yet.

> In Magento 1, Inventory information is stored in a Stock Item object.
>   Each Stock Item object is associated with a product object. Magento
>   persists Stock Item objects to the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.
>
> However, each Stock Item object has a related Stock Status object.
>   Stock Status appears to be an (index|cache|de-normalized) table that
>   stores a product's stock status as in integer constant, and allows you
>   to associate multiple stock items and products with a different
>   `website_id`. Magento persists stock status objects to the
>   `cataloginventory_stock_status`. The class constants and table schema
>   for this are below.

```
class Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status extends 
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK       = 0;
    const STATUS_IN_STOCK           = 1;
}

mysql> describe cataloginventory_stock_status;
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id   | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| website_id   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stock_id     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| qty          | decimal(12,4)        | NO   |     | 0.0000  |       |
| stock_status | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

> However... there is also a qty column in this table.
>
> qty in `cataloginventory_stock_item` is the source of truth, and qty in
>   `cataloginventory_stock_status` is the cached/indexed value. Rebuilding
>   the Stock Status index appears to always copy the value from
>   `cataloginventory_stock_item` into `cataloginventory_stock_status`. If
>   there are multiple websites, there will also be a record for each
>   product_id/website_id combo in `cataloginventory_stock_status`. This
>   suggests the possibility of different stock levels per website, but as
>   far as I can tell the qty value is always the same for each one.

So the upshot of this is, not only do we need to update qty in `cataloginventory_stock_item` which is what we've achieved so far... we also need to kick off the re-indexing...

In a community version of Magento an re-index is kicked off in

```
/**
 * Refresh stock index for specific stock items after succesful order placement
 *
 * @param $observer
 */
public function reindexQuoteInventory($observer)
{
    // Reindex quote ids
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $productIds = array();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $productIds[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getProductId();
        $children   = $item->getChildrenItems();
        if ($children) {
            foreach ($children as $childItem) {
                $productIds[$childItem->getProductId()] = $childItem->getProductId();
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($productIds)) {
        Mage::getResourceSingleton('cataloginventory/indexer_stock')->reindexProducts($productIds);
    }

    // Reindex previously remembered items
    $productIds = array();
    foreach ($this->_itemsForReindex as $item) {
        $item->save();
        $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
    }
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_indexer_price')->reindexProductIds($productIds);

    $this->_itemsForReindex = array(); // Clear list of remembered items - we don't need it anymore

    return $this;
}
```

It's interesting to note that in community, not only is Magento re-indexing stock status but also product price - this presumably is because tier pricing is dependent on stock availability??

but for enterprise there is different logic

```
/**
 * Refresh stock index for specific stock items after succesful order placement
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Enterprise_CatalogInventory_Model_Index_Observer
 */
public function reindexQuoteInventory($observer)
{
    Mage::log('logged in enterprise',null,'wrtInventory.log',true);
    foreach ($this->_itemsForReindex as $item) {
        $item->save();
        Mage::log(var_export($item,true),null,'wrtInventory.log',true);
    }
    $this->_itemsForReindex = array(); // Clear list of remembered items - we don't need it anymore
    return $this;
}
```

This seems to have been changed in Enterprise to prevent deadlocking the database and a duplicate insert into indexer *_tmp tables as detailed [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/152)

The upshot of which is that the qty value `cataloginventory_stock_status` doesn't update in enterprise on placing an order but instead waits until some other action kicks off a reindex... (a product save or maybe its being run on a cron somewhere).

So the full solution for Un-Cancel assuming you are on Community is:

```
//set the state back to Pending
$order->setState(
    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW,
    true,
    'Reset Order',
    false
    );

    $order->setStatus('pending');

    $order->setBaseDiscountCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseShippingCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseSubtotalCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseTaxCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseTotalCanceled(0);
    $order->setDiscountCanceled(0);
    $order->setShippingCanceled(0);
    $order->setSubtotalCanceled(0);
    $order->setTaxCanceled(0);
    $order->setTotalCanceled(0);

    $stockItems = [];
    $productIds = [];

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            /** @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
            $item->setQtyCanceled(0);
            $item->setTaxCanceled(0);
            $item->setHiddenTaxCanceled(0);
            $item->save();

            $stockItems[$item->getProductId()] = ['qty'=>$item->getQtyOrdered()];
            $productIds[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getProductId();
            $children   = $item->getChildrenItems();
            if ($children) {
                foreach ($children as $childItem) {
                    $productIds[$childItem->getProductId()] = $childItem->getProductId();
                }
            }
        }


    /** @var Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock $stockModel */
    $stockModel = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock');
    $itemsForReindex = $stockModel->registerProductsSale($stockItems);

    if (count($productIds)) {
        Mage::getResourceSingleton('cataloginventory/indexer_stock')->reindexProducts($productIds);
    } 

    $stockProductIds = array();
    foreach ($itemsForReindex as $item) {
        $item->save();
        $stockProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
    }
    if (count($stockProductIds)) {
        Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_indexer_price')->reindexProductIds($stockProductIds);
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

I'll let those on Enterprise figure out the simpler logic themselves, but suffice it to say that you only need to call save on the items contained within `itemsForReindex` and don't need to worry about actually calling the 2 index functions.

```
foreach ($itemsForReindex as $item) {
    $item->save();
}
```

Comment: Great and elaborate answer! If the asking guy ever decides to accept an answer (after almost 5 years now) I definitely suggest this one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this free extension for this: http://mamoc.com/uncancel-order

**UPDATE:** It adds a button to the order view page when the order status is cancelled. When you undo a cancelled order the extension also updates the product stock information and sets the order state to pending allowing you to process the order like any other.

Comment: Please give more details about the extension. A simple link is not the best answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the answer with some more details.

Comment: Note that the link to the extension has changed and it's not free anymore https://genmato.com/uncancel-order

Comment: It's still on github https://github.com/mamocbv/UnCancel

Answer (score 1):

What if I tell you a simpler and easier way...
Try using this extension and it really works well: 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/undo-cancel-orders.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need the same in M2, you can uncancel order using this product. It restores order to its orignal state.

https://marketplace.magento.com/addify-uncancel.html