# How to create invioce for cancel order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, magento-1, sales-order, invoice

I want to create the **invoice** for **cancel** order. How can it possible?

**OR**

Any way to Change the **order item** status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, **you can't invoice a canceled order.**

My suggestion would be to **uncancel the order first** by using [the script in this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/is-there-any-way-to-get-back-the-cancelled-order)

An alternative would be to **modify `sales_flat_order_item` in the `qty_canceled` column for the order you want to modify.**

Once you've uncancel the order, you can just invoice it ;)

Comment: can you add manual solution  table `sales_flat_order_item` column `qty_canceled` change value there will do the trick. can you add this in your solution i don't want to add mine.