# Restore Cancelled Order Code Question

Tags: magento-1.8

I just found this on **another question** but I'm **unable to comment** because of my reputation.

```
$incrementId = '1000001'; //replace this with the increment id of your actual order
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

if ($order) {
    $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
    $order->setStatus('pending');

    $order->setBaseDiscountCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseShippingCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseSubtotalCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseTaxCanceled(0);
    $order->setBaseTotalCanceled(0);
    $order->setDiscountCanceled(0);
    $order->setShippingCanceled(0);
    $order->setSubtotalCanceled(0);
    $order->setTaxCanceled(0);
    $order->setTotalCanceled(0);

    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
        $item->setQtyCanceled(0);
        $item->setTaxCanceled(0);
        $item->setHiddenTaxCanceled(0);
        $item->save();
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

[Is there any way to get back the cancelled order?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/is-there-any-way-to-get-back-the-cancelled-order)

Do I put this code into a php file, upload it via ftp then run it?

We are using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Thanks,
Callam

Comment: Yes, you can put the code in php file and run it on your FTP with your Order increment ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this in your root folder. You just have to add some lines:

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$incrementId  = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
$userIp       = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(true);
$allowed      = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips'));

if ($incrementId && in_array($userIp, $allowed)) {
    // your code here
}
```

Now you can call it from browser liker `yourdomain.com/filename.php?id=xxxxxxxx`, but i'd recommend to add some security checks - either IP restriction, or if you have shell access make it only executable from there.

***Edit:** added IP check - can be set in `Admin -> System -> Config -> Dev -> allowed IPs`*

Comment: Thanks. This is just for a one time thing as I'm working on getting the PayPal function sorted on the website.